# Configuration of power rail and DC to DC converters on design with li-ion cell's virtual ground

Tags: power-supply, batteries, virtual-ground

I need to isolate the two Li-ion cells from the circuit when they get charged from USB, otherwise I have grounding/shorting issues because I use a virtual ground to obtain a split supply.

I thought to use an LTC4412 two drive two MOSFET to break the battery+ and the virtual ground paths to the rest of the circuit when the USB 5V are present.

Do you think it could work?

[image]

Comment: Define work?  with expectations of VI specs and tolerances

Comment: It is hard to figure out what you're (trying to) do(ing) in your schematic. It would help a lot if you add a **simplified** schematic (there's a schematic entry tool for that) to make more clear what your schematic is doing. Disconnecting a ground for a balanced supply sounds like asking for trouble in my opinion. Are you sure you're not **shorting** the battery that is connected to ground? I would just use the 8.4 V supply and make a virtual ground with an opamp. Or just use a single cell and a DCDC converter to make -4.2 V.

Comment: @tony no more like if it's a good idea

Comment: @bimpel, The current needed is about 300mA per supply infact the LDOs are rated for 500mA also the voltage supply cannot exceed 5.8V. I liked the idea of a specular supply, but It is trouble and time eating. If this would not have worked,  i though to use a switching regulator to invert a single cell's voltage or still two of them in series, even though I wanted to avoid switching supply

Comment: It could be made to work with balancing, but there are simpler ways.   And asking if it will work without specs is a bit opportunistic.

Answer (score 1):

A better scheme would be this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXPBG4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why? because using the batteries to generate the rails can create problems if one battery draws more than the other on charge, then one rail goes down and that can create problems for the virtual ground.

Use one battery (or battery pack) and then use an oring circuit to drive the positive and negative rails. This also allows for not having to worry about the ground. There are DC\DC converters that can generate a negative voltage from a positive rail.